# How do I install KDE and retain LightDM as a login manager?

Tags: kubuntu, package-management, lightdm

I want to install KDE in my Ubuntu 12.04 .

I am using LightDM. So how can I fully install KDE? I do not want to remove LightDM.

I want KDE but without any confliction with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Display managers**

There can be multiple display managers installed. You can then pick/change the default dm by running the dpkg-reconfigure.

man dpkg-reconfigure

```
NAME
       dpkg-reconfigure - reconfigure an already installed package

SYNOPSIS
        dpkg-reconfigure [options] packages

DESCRIPTION
       dpkg-reconfigure reconfigures packages after they have already been installed. Pass it the names of a
       package or packages to reconfigure. It will ask configuration questions, much like when the package
       was first installed.

       If you just want to see the current configuration of a package, see debconf-show(1) instead.
```

**Changing dm (kdm/gdm/lightdm)**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm
```

[image]

**Lightdm-KDE**

There is also: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/lightdm-kde-greeter

> Package: lightdm-kde-greeter
>
> LightDM KDE greeter

**LightDM KDE developer's blog**

David Edmundson's Web Log: http://www.sharpley.org.uk/

Direct links:

KDE and LightDM revisited: http://www.sharpley.org.uk/node/26

An Update on LightDM KDE: http://www.sharpley.org.uk/blog/an-update-on-lightdm-kde

Google Two-Step Authentication On Your Desktop: http://www.sharpley.org.uk/lightdm-google-authentication

The plan for LightDM-0.2: http://www.sharpley.org.uk/blog/whats_coming_lightdm_02

Answer (score 8):

Simplest way of doing this is to install Kubuntu and when its installed opening a terminal and typing `sudo apt-get install lightdm`.

When you do that `dpkg` will ask you which login manager you want to use between the ones you have installed in your system. You need only to choose `lightdm` and that is all. You will have KDE, KDM and LightDM installed and you will be using LightDM as login manager.

---

If you already have a working Unity desktop and you want also to use KDE as a choice, you need to install the KDE desktop environment from the Ubuntu Software Center or with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`.

Then just reinstall `lightdm` or use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to reconfigure your system to use LightDM.

Comment: in 2022 this doesnt seem to be working, but using lightdm-gtk-greeter in this answer did: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577597/346155