# How to change login screen

Tags: login, kde, login-screen

After installing kde, I had an ugly splash and login screen that I didn't like. I managed to get the splash back to normal, but I can't get the login back to normal.

Comment: I tried installing lightdm but It didn't change the login screen.

Comment: you could try `sudo apt-get purge lightdm-kde-greeter` but that very well may just uninstall kde (plasma desktop plasma this plasma that etc...) along with it so proceed with caution and only accept the changes after reviewing the changes to be made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install another display manager such as LightDM, MDM, Slim, GDM

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

select LightDM

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

You can add greeters to have nice themes [How to change the LightDM theme/greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter)

There is also `lightdm-kde-greeter` mentioned here [How do I install KDE and retain LightDM as a login manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146320/how-do-i-install-kde-and-retain-lightdm-as-a-login-manager)

Comment: I finally found the answer buried deep in one of the non accepted answers of  http://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

**for 13.10 or older**

use the following command to set lightdm back to normal

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --greeter unity-greeter
```

reboot for the changes to take effect

This works for going from xubuntu and back to unity-greeter, ubuntustudio and back, and kubuntu back to unity-greeter as well.

---

**14.04**

There is no longer a `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file and the set-defaults command is no longer available.

Taking a look at my old 13.10 files, I discovered what changes need to be made to select `unity-greeter`.

There needs to be a file named `50-unity-greeter.conf` located in the directory `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` run the following commands to create and/or update this file to use the `unity-greeter`:

```
echo '[SeatDefaults]' | sudo tee /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
echo 'greeter-session=unity-greeter' | sudo tee -a /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

Don't forget to save any unsaved files before you restart `lightdm` because you will be logged out!!!

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal crt - alt T and use the commnad chfn to add Real Name in /etc/passwd, open /etc/login.defs (as root) and look for the line containing CHFN_RESTRICT. Change whatever is followed to frwh. This will allow changing Real Name from KDE System Settings.